# Telephone Server, Telephones, Printers, PCs & Servers on Individual VLAN's, DHCP clashing

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2008, telephony

As a requirement for being taken over by a corporation we have been asked to stop using a firewall (Juniper SSG-140) to separate our telephone system from the main LAN. Our idea, VLANs. With some research tonight we have put our plan to action and are having some big issues.

We have some GS748T's and TP's, the 1 TP with all telephones on and IPCortex telephony server on. The GS748T's (there's 2) switch all workstations/laptops from patch panels. When the GS748TP is plugged into the main LAN the phones aren't asking the IPCortex for an IP it's asking our main DHCP server (win server 2008).

We have all telephones and the IPCortex on VLAN 20 and Port 1 is VLAN 10 communicating with the main LAN. They are separated in such a way that the phone SHOULD only ask the IPCortex for its IP. Where have we gone wrong? It feels like the Netgears are using a different layer of broadcast or something, bypassing the VLANs.

Does anyone have any experience in this?